# Blazor: How to set as Required a parameter for custom component

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

Example:

I have the following class:

```cs
  public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        [Required]
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
```

where I set the property Summary to Required

I have a  razor component where I set that property

```cs
<InputText DisplayName="Test" @bind-Value="Text"></InputText>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string? Text { get; set; }   

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> TextChanged { get; set; }

}
```

in this razor page I use the Edit Form to set it:

```cs
@using TestRequired.Data;

<EditForm Model="wheater">
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    Component
    <TestEditorComponent @bind-Text="wheater.Summary" />
    Input Text
    <InputText DisplayName="Test" @bind-Value="wheater.Summary"></InputText>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</EditForm>
@code {
    WeatherForecast wheater = new WeatherForecast();

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

when I try to submit an empty string, I receive the following result:

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKzd7.png)

The first one, is my component and it is not highlighted. Instead the input text, is correctly red.

How can I automatic highlight my components in a form if the binded property in the Model is required?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a composite control of some type, you need to manually map the bind "triumvirate" like this into the child component:

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<InputText DisplayName="Test" Value="Text" ValueChanged="TextChanged" ValueExpression="this.TextExpression" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> TextChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>>? TextExpression { get; set; }
}
```

"Bind" is a Razor directive not C#.